# PDF Form Filling using XSL/XML in Java

Tags: pdf-generation, apache-fop

I am working on proof of concept for generating PDF filled forms (usually forms from government say IRS tax form and other sites), data will be coming from JSON or XML.

I was evaluating Apache FOP for this where XML is data part and XSL is formatting part but my question is how I can XSL for complex forms?  I tried to search if I can get it already on these sites but no luck.

Usually should we create XSL manually by reverse engineering PDF forms?

Certain forms I am using for examples are really complex for reverse engineering.

Thanks,
Rushik.

Comment: RenderX has a commercial application called VisualXSL where you can import an existing PDF and design on top of it. It exports XSL for use in XSL FO solutions.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, Do you know if we have any open source counterpart for similar functionality?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know of anything that has similar functionality to VisualXSL.